# React router 4 - Why is my component only rendered on manually setting the url but not on clicking a Link with same url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I started using react router v4 and I have 2 questions. Ive been researching and reading about router 4 but cant explain why the following happens:
ps. I have included only code I thought is relevant, please let me know if I should dd more.

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <div>
       <Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
       <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew}></Route>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

PostsIndex:

```
<Link to="/posts/new">Add a Post</Link>
```

1.  What happens with my code below is on route '/' I am being shown PostsNew Component. When I manually put url to '/posts/new' both components are being rendered - PostsIndex and PostsNew which is intended. HOWEVER, when im on '/' and click on my Link (with path: /posts/new) nothing happens. The PostsNew component is not being rendered unless I refresh the page (so the url already changed after I click the link but I need to refresh it-url stays same- and only then will the nested component being rendered). Why does this happen?

Another question: 
Below I want to achieve the opposite- NOT nesting routes. When I use switch and put the most specific route first, it works. Also when I click on the Link, the PostsNew is being rendered without the need to refresh. My question is just to understand routing better:

1. I would expect in my code below, both components being rendered on /posts/new - but here the PostsNew component is NEVER being rendered. Why?
2. Why is my Link working when I use Switch and if I dont I must manually refresh/put url? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I've created a reduced test case for your scenario and the Link clicking works as expected (shows both components). Here's a link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wxkeur So the root cause might be in  your components... Could you share your code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I just found out, my problems resulted from me using an old version of react-router-dom (ive been watching a tutorial and havent checked which versions Im installing as it was a router 4 tutorial..). Now having switched to the right version the link works :) Just one question to double check i understand it all: Is it correct that I cannot use Switch when I want to next routes and would have to put outside switch and those I dont want any nesting insight switch?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a specific path to render you need to add an exact attribute to the Routes:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
<Route exact path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew}/>
```